# Convex function dominance

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, convex-analysis

I am stuck in the following exercice for about a week, I decided to post it to get some help if possible, thanks.

Let $f : [0,+\infty) \to  [0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$.

Does there exist a **convex** function $g :  [0,+\infty) \to  [0,+\infty)$ such that $g \geq f$ and $ \lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x)=0$?

The idea I have, but I am unable to conclude with it, is as follows:
Let $[0,+\infty) =\bigcup_{k} I_{k}$, where $(I_{k})$ a sequence of intervals of length $l_{k} \to 0 $.
We aim to construct a piecewise linear function that satisfies the conditions. Graphically, this seems possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $(n_{i})$ is a strictly increasing sequence such that $n_{1}<n_{1}+1<n_{2}<n_{2}+2<n_{3}<\cdots$ and that $f(x)<\dfrac{1}{i+1}$ for all $x\geq n_{i}$. We let $L_{0}$ the spline joining $(0,M)$ and $(n_{1},1)$ where $M>0$ is large enough such that the spline $L_{1}$ joining $(n_{1},1)$ and $(n_{2},1/2)$ has slope greater than $L_{0}$, we now let $L_{2}$ be the spline joining $(n_{2},1/2)$ and $(n_{3},1/3)$, the splines $L_{n}$ for $n\geq 3$ are defined in the same fashion. Then the function $g=L_{0}\chi_{[0,n_{1}]}+\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}L_{i}\chi_{[n_{i},n_{i+1}]}$ is convex since the slopes of $L_{i}$ are increasing.

Comment: This $g$ is piecewise constant, and hence not convex.

Comment: @user284331 , thank you a lot  amazing , please what do you the spline joinning $(0,M)$ and $(n_{1},1)$ , I am not used to the english appelation .... thank you again for you help

Comment: The slope of the spline $L_{1}$ is $-\dfrac{1}{2(n_{2}-n_{1}}$, and we let $M>0$ so large such that $\dfrac{M-1}{n_{1}}>\dfrac{1}{2(n_{2}-n_{1}}$, now set $L_{0}$ to be the spline joining $(0,M)$ and $(n_{1},1)$. Note that we also need $M>0$ large enough such that $L_{0}(x)>f(x)$ for all  $x\in[0,n_{1}]$.